# ionic angular app directive not calling method on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my directive below, I have tried adding a method `roll()` to be called, it does not. I am thinking i might be on the wrong scope or something, tried adding it on two different... Any clues?

```
.controller('RollViewCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.someTitle='BLA';
      $scope.isRolling = true;
      $scope.roll = function(){
        console.log('roll Called');
      };

      /*jshint multistr: true */
    }).directive('myDice', [ function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="wrapper">\
                          <button id="rollButton" class="button button-dark button-full button-positive" ngClick="roll()">\
                          Roll</button>\
                          <input id="secondroll" name="roll" type="checkbox">\
                          <input id="roll" name="roll" type="checkbox">\
                          <label for="roll">Roll it!</label>\
                          <label for="secondroll"><span>Stop!</span></label>\
                          <div id="platform">\
                            <div id="dice">\
                              <div class="side front">\
                                <div class="dot center"></div>\
                              </div>\
                              <div class="side front inner"></div>\
                              <div class="side top">\
                                <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>\
                                <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>\
                              </div>\
                            .......
                            </div>\
                          </div>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { scope.roll = function() { alert('hi'); }}
      };
    }]);
```

Comment: off the top of my head, I think you might need to rename ngClick to ng-click or ng:click

Comment: I think @Mutahhir is correct and I'd like to add that all angular directives that are named with camel case(ngClick, ngClass, ngStyle etc) get converted to dashes: ng-click, ng-style, ng-class.